# Spanish Number Method Parameters & Loops

Tags: java, methods, parameters

have to do an exercise called SpanishNumbers. Create a SpanishNumbers application that displays numbers 1 through 10 in Spanish. A method with an int parameter should display the Spanish word for the number passed. A loop structure in the main() method should be used to call the method ten times. The Spanish word equivalents for numbers 1 through 10 are:

1 uno, 2 dos, 3 tres, 4 cuatro, 5 cinco, 6 seis, 7 siete, 8 ocho, 9 nueve, 10 diez.

```
package chapter7java;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Eric
 */
public class SpanishNumbers {

    public static void spanNum(int num, String word) {

        for (int i = 1; i<= num; i++) {
            if (num = 1) {
                System.out.println("Uno");
            }
        }
    }



    public static void main (String [] args) {

        for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
    }

}
```

So before you freak out, I'm having trouble even starting this thing so maybe give me some tip hows I can do what it asks, not finish the work necessarily. What I posted was just crap so just let me know how I can go about starting this. Thanks in advance! This is beginner java so keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

The function `spanNum` needs only an int as a parameter. Remove the String parameter passed to it. Replace

```
public static void spanNum(int num, String word) {
```

with

```
public static void spanNum(int num) {
```

The spanNum function is supposed to print the Spanish for one number (the one passed in parameter num). So there should be no loop. Also `=` is an assignment statement, not a comparison operator. The comparison operator is `==`. So the statement to test if num is equal to 1 would be `if(num == 1)`.

In the main, you could call `spanNum` in the loop for all values of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to create an array to hold your spanish numbers.

```
String[] numbers = {"uno", "dos", "tres", ......}
```

Declare that inside your `spanNum` method; you then just print out the value at index `i` to convert it into spanish.  Just remember that array indices start at 0, so you'll need to shift
your index by one.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the line `if(num = 1)` should be `if(num == 1)` since = assigns and == compares. Second, when you are planning to take one number and do different things based on its value, a `switch` block may be more useful than multiple `if...else if` blocks. Third, in your main method, you are simply outputting the loop control variable, i, each time instead of calling spanNum().